# IFCjs add differents models in the same scene

Tags: model, ifc

I do not know if this would be the channel to ask a question that is happening to me in IFCjs.
I am trying to add two separate models that belong to the same work and these two are coming to me in different origins, when the coordinates of them should overlap and appear correlated.
I add the models as follows:

```
await this.ifcLoader.ifcManager.applyWebIfcConfig({
            COORDINATE_TO_ORIGIN: true,
            USE_FAST_BOOLS: true,
 });
this.ifcLoader.load(url, (ifcModel) => {     
            this.scene.add(ifcModel);
   });
```

This is the result:

[image]

But when use https://iloveifc.com/: (image2)
[image]

Are correlated.

Would anyone know what I’m doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

What `COORDINATE_TO_ORIGIN` does is to take the first triangle found in the IFC and put it in the origin. We are using that approach because that's the only reliable way in 100% of the IFC files. To coordinate multiple models you can use that only in the first model, and then retrieve the transformation matrix applied to that model and apply it to the rest.

```
let firstModel = true;

function loadIfc(url) {

  const settings = this.loader.ifcManager.state.webIfcSettings;
  const fastBools = settings?.USE_FAST_BOOLS || true;

  await loader.ifcManager.applyWebIfcConfig({
    COORDINATE_TO_ORIGIN: firstModel,
    USE_FAST_BOOLS: fastBools
  });

  const ifcModel = await loader.loadAsync(url, onProgress);

  if (firstModel) {
    const matrixArr = await 
    loader.ifcManager.ifcAPI.GetCoordinationMatrix(
      ifcModel.modelID
    );
    const matrix = new Matrix4().fromArray(matrixArr);
    loader.ifcManager.setupCoordinationMatrix(matrix);
  }

  firstModel = false;

}
```